# How to use a C++ extern constant variable for a template argument in a different file

Tags: c++, templates, extern, bitset

I have the following 5 files: global_vars.h, global_vars.cpp content.h content.cpp main.cpp.

global_vars.h

```
#ifndef global_vars_h
#define global_vars_h

namespace Constants{

    extern const unsigned int b;

}

#endif
```

global_vars.cpp

```
#include "global_vars.h"

namespace Constants{

    extern const unsigned int b(5);


}
```

content.h

```
#ifndef CONTENT_H_
#define CONTENT_H_

#include "global_vars.h"
#include <bitset>

struct a{

    std::bitset<Constants::b> s;
    int a=10;

};

#endif
```

content.cpp

```
#include "content.h"

a xVar;
```

main.cpp

```
#include "content.h"
int main(){
   return 0;
}
```

I get the following errors:

```
In file included from content.cpp:1:0:
content.h:11:31: error: the value of ‘Constants::b’ is not usable in a constant expression

In file included from content.h:4:0,
from content.cpp:1:
global_vars.h:6:28: note: ‘Constants::b’ was not initialized with a constant expression
extern const unsigned int b;
```

I have to use Constants::b in files other than content.cpp/.h (for other bitsets) as well so how can I go around doing this? Appreciate the help.

thanks

Comment: You should not have the keyword "extern" in global_vars.cpp . It prevents the compiler to create the variable in the binary global_vars.o. You will get a link error, saying the variable is undefined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you ask is not possible.

In C++, templates are resolved entirely by the compiler, the linker only gets to see fully instantiated bodies of template classes and functions. The compiler only gets to see code that is in a given compilation unit.

Therefore, even if an `int` is `extern const` and assigned a value in some compilation unit (making it valid at run-time), it cannot possibly be used as a template parameter in any other compilation unit. There would be no way for the compiler to know the value of that `int` at the time that it is resolving which template instantiations refer to the same types.

The closest you can get most likely, is that you could a pointer to that `int` as a template parameter, and then if you have e.g. a function using that template parameter which is run at run-time, it could dereference the pointer to get the constant value. If you have link-time optimizations enabled it might even inline it, I'm not sure.

Comment: Can I use a #define in the global_vars.h to circumvent it?

Comment: Sure, if there is a global include file you could even do something like `struct my_constants { static constexpr int my_int = 42; };` I think, which might be nicer than a macro